# Linux's continue statement

Tags: c, linux

I often see Linux code with something like this

```
if (condition1)
     continue;

.....
```

Now that doesn't make much sense, if condition1 it will continue to next line of code. If not condition1 it still fall through to next line of code.  it doesn't have an alternative place to go if condition1 is not met.

any ideas?

Comment: `continue` means to go directly to the bottom of the enclosing loop.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what the continue statement does.  It means skip the remaining code in the current loop and continue to iterate if the loop condition is still true.

Comment: (Has nothing to do with Linux -- a standard C feature, and also present in Java and several other languages.)

Answer (score 2):

The `continue` statement does not mean to continue on the next line. It causes the remaining portion of the enclosing for, while or do-while loop body to be skipped.

Refer to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/continue) (or many other places) for a description of the keyword.

`continue` is a feature of the C programming language (as well as many languages including C++, Java, etc). It is not specific to Linux.

I've often thought the name is counter-intuitive. In perl, even though much of the syntax is C-like, the keyword `next` is used to skip to the next loop iteration, which seems more intuitive to me.