# what is this "continue" does exactly?

Tags: c

I have this part of the code, I don't understand. I know "continue" in if, skips that statement. But why? It supposed to print out an array like "  `073.45 * C`". The `i=2` is for the numbers, right? what does `Temp_s[5-i}=result%10+0x30` do? Can someone explain this code please.

```
void Convert_data_to_temp(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long result;
    unsigned char i=0;
    result=((33*1000*data)/4096)%100000;//rounding off to maximum 5 digits

    Temp_s[0]=0x30;
    Temp_s[3]='.';
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(i==2){continue;}
        Temp_s[5-i]=(result%10)+0x30;
        result=result/10;
    }
    Temp_s[i]=32;
    Temp_s[i+1]=32;
    Temp_s[i+2]='*';
    Temp_s[i+3]=32;
    Temp_s[i+4]='C';
    Temp_s[i+5]=13;
    Temp_s[i+6]=10;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `continue` continues `for` loop execution

Comment: It'll make the loop go to the next iteration

Comment: In other words, Temp_s only runs if i = 0, 1, 3, 4, or 5.  It doesn't run when i is 2.

Comment: Read some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/continue).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux's continue statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26350154/linuxs-continue-statement)

Comment: when i=2, it will calculate the result and place it in temp_s[2]. the rest of temp_s are for space (32), and other ASCII characters. but what does the if do when i is not equal to 2.

Comment: Using `32` instead of `' '`, and `13` instead of `'\r'`, and `10` instead of `'\n'` is … not sensible, shall we say.  That's polite understatement, of course.  Similarly, using `0x30` instead of `'0'` is equally counter-productive most of the time.

Comment: Why has this question been slammed so hard?  Basically punishing someone for less than perfect wording although the intent was so clear there are good helpful answers.  Why not improve the question by editing and help make SO a better resource.  This is a fine question with some fine answers

Answer (score 3):

Well that's a nice mess for sure. Here's what this code does (assuming there's a `Temp_s` char array in scope that has at least 13 elements).

```
void Convert_data_to_temp(unsigned long data)
{
    unsigned long result;
    unsigned char i=0;

    // Calculate... something.
    // Apparently the calculation is done in fixed-point decimal,
    // with 3 decimal places (hence `*1000`).
    // Also, the comment is wrong: that's not rounding off, the result will wrap.
    // In any case, we can be sure that 0 <= result < 100000.
    result=((33*1000*data)/4096)%100000;//rounding off to maximum 5 digits

    Temp_s[0]=0x30; // ASCII for '0'
    Temp_s[3]='.';

    // Now Temp_s looks like this (? represents an indeterminate value:
    //
    // 0 ? ? . ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?

    // Now we're filling Temp_s backwards from the 5th index,
    // with the respective digits of `result`. The `continue` skips over
    // index 3 so we don't overwrite the '.' we just put there.
    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if(i==2){continue;}
        Temp_s[5-i]=(result%10)+0x30; // Again, 0x30 is just ASCII '0'.
        result=result/10;
    }

    // Let's say that result was 12345. Now Temp_s looks like this:
    //
    // 1 2 3 . 4 5 ? ? ? ? ? ? ?

    // And now we fill the rest of Temp_s with these hard-coded values.
    // Note that we retrieve i at the value it was left by the for, i.e. 6.
    Temp_s[i]=32;   // 32 is an ASCII space
    Temp_s[i+1]=32;
    Temp_s[i+2]='*';
    Temp_s[i+3]=32;
    Temp_s[i+4]='C';
    Temp_s[i+5]=13; // ASCII Carriage return
    Temp_s[i+6]=10; // ASCII Line feed

    // In the end, Temp_s looks like this:
    //
    // 1 2 3 . 4 5 [space] [space] * [space] C \r \n
}
```

Apparently the code is broken, too: the computation of `result` hints at 3-decimals fixed-point, but the representation ends up with only two decimals, and overwrites the `'0'` that was assigned at the very beginning.

I suggest you just throw that crazy code away and use the tried-and-true standard library:

```
snprintf(
    Temp_s, sizeof Temp_s,
    "%.3lu.%.2lu  * C\r\n",
    result / 100, result % 100
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code as a whole converts a 5-digit decimal number such as 54321 into `"543.21  * C\r\n"` — except that it doesn't ensure that the string is null terminated.  However, if the target array `Temp_s` is a global variable and is big enough and is only written to by this function, then probably there is a null at the end already, but it is simpler and safer to make sure.

The assignment `Temp_s[0]=0x30;` could be dropped, and the loop could be written more clearly as:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    if (i == 2)
        Temp_s[5-i] = '.';
    else
    {
        Temp_s[5-i] = (result % 10) + '0';
        result /= 10;
    }
}
strcpy(&Temp_s[6], "  * C\r\n");  // Adds null termination
```

Frankly, though, it could (and maybe should) be written as a call to `sprintf()` (which also ensures that the string is null terminated):

```
int dp = result % 100;
int un = result / 100;
sprintf(Temp_s, "%.3d.%.2d  * C\r\n", un, dp);
```

You could write instead (noting that `result` is an `unsigned long`, hence the change of format conversion specifier):

```
sprintf(Temp_s, "%.3lu.%.2lu  * C\r\n", result / 100, result % 100);
```

It would be preferable to be able to use `snprintf()`, but it isn't clear how this global variable is declared, and using `sizeof(Temp_s)` might not be correct:

```
snprintf(Temp_s, sizeof(Temp_s), "%.3lu.%.2lu  * C\r\n", result / 100, result % 100);
```

Comment: You can also use [standard C `div()` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.2): `div_t d = div( result, 100 );` and then use `d.quot` and `d.rem`.  That would result in only performing one division operation, which may be expensive on the hardware.

Answer (score 0):

```
Temp_s[5-i]=(result%10)+0x30;
```

Writes at index 5-i of the array Temp_s 
The result modulo 10 + 48.

The continue skips the statements in the loop and goes back to the i++ statement and after that to the predicate of the loop. But only if i is equal to two.

All in all this should give you the result calculated before as a string representation.

The if i==2 preserves that you do not overwrite the `'.'`.

Comment: Additional hint: `0x30` is needless obfuscation for the ASCII character `'0'`.

Comment: The `continue` goes to the `i++` part of the loop and then the condition, not directly to the condition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks for your help. This function, void Convert_data_to_temp(unsigned long data), displays the temp_s on the LCD. So it needs to be an output of this function. snprintf is just to print; How can I use this ""%.3lu.%.2lu  * C\r\n", result / 100, result % 100);" in the function to get the temp_s as output.

Comment: @AliyarAttaran: In your code in the question, `Temp_s` is a global variable, so there's no need to get it as output; the function simply modifies the global and everyone goes home happy — unless you've got multiple threads at work, or need to call it multiple times, or otherwise run foul of 'global variables are not a good idea'.  It would be preferable to change the interface to the function to pass a pointer to an array of `char` (along with its size) and have the function format the data into that string.  It then becomes thread-safe and reusable — it gets rid of the problems with globals.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird.  Looks like you're iterating over that for loop, but you're not executing the code for i == 2.  The continue statement sends you to the next iteration of the for loop before you do anything.

That'd the kind of code that'd really benefit from a well-placed comment..

Comment: That's actually a fairly common idiom in C. Start a loop, then the first statement inside is "if (...) continue", meaning "loop over all these things, except this one".

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker The *what* is obvious.  But *why* skip the loop iteration when `i == 2`?  That's a reason for comments - explain *why* something is done.  Putting a comment in like `/* skip when i is 2 */` should get any experienced coder nothing but "You're the master of the obvious" ridicule.

Comment: Exactly Andrew - comment to say what the code is doing are useless (and often untrue after a couple rounds of modifications).  But what you need is to know WHY some poor soul felt compelled to do those gyrations..